# Enable Cloud Indexing on existing Search Service Application

Tags: enterprise-search, sharepoint-search

Is it possible to enable `Cloud Indexing` on an existing `Search Service Application`? We have a multi server farm with a `Search Service Application Indexing` multiple `Content Sources` like On-Premise SharePoint, SQL & MySQL data via `BAInsight Custom Connector` and also displaying Federated O365 SharePoint and People results.

Comment: You didn't mention the version of SharePoint, you are working on.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the Cloud SSAs are basically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to convert an existing SSA to a Cloud SSA. This is outlined at [Create a cloud Search service application in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/0bba350d-ec33-43db-a873-930559c78dee%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_CreateCloudSSA).